# NoClassDefFoundError when deploying on QA server

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

Iv come across an error that seems to happen more frequently to people, but the source differs in a wide range of causes. After deploying the project on a server where the testers can test it, at some places when performing a task in the application this error the < NoClassDefFoundError > pops up.

Now iv read a lot on the internet, to some people it happens because there is a jar miss match to some because they don't have certain permissions in their environment some are missing some dependencies. But that does seem to be the case for me.

Or I am just getting frustrated, I am not sure anymore to be honest. So in hopes that someone sees something in the stack trace that might have skipped my sight or something i turned to Stack Overflow in hopes of salvation....

Now I know that this class is located in the < jaxb-api > jar. In the project pom its set to use the version 2.2.2 . I even decompiled the jar using an online decompiler to check the jar out. The class exists. And in my local environment it works fine. Only after deploying on the server does this happen.

Thank you in advance!!! And sorry if my question is unclear, I will edit it to make it more clear if that might be the case.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/DatatypeConverterImpl$CalendarFormatter
    at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._printDate(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:482)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.printDate(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:478)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDate(DatatypeConverter.java:680)
    at org.w3._2001.xmlschema.Adapter1.marshal(Adapter1.java:20)
    at org.w3._2001.xmlschema.Adapter1.marshal(Adapter1.java:7)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.AdaptedAccessor.get(AdaptedAccessor.java:72)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.writeLeafElement(TransducedAccessor.java:252)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:121)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:316)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleReferenceNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleReferenceNodeProperty.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:152)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:168)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:155)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:152)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:152)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:264)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.marshal(BridgeImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.api.Bridge.marshal(Bridge.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:321)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:284)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:146)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:94)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:598)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:222)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy653.majQuittances(Unknown Source)
    at com.satec.dao.winpass.WinpassPolicyDAO.submitQuittance(WinpassPolicyDAO.java:45)
    at com.satec.service.WinpassService.submitPolicyLifecycle(WinpassService.java:505)
    at com.satec.service.WinpassService.submitPolicyLifecycle(WinpassService.java:330)
    at com.satec.service.WinpassHelper.submitPolicyLifecycle(WinpassHelper.java:96)
    at com.satec.manager.SANewPolicyAvoidanceBP.executeAvoidance(SANewPolicyAvoidanceBP.java:51)
    at com.satec.manager.SANewPolicyAvoidanceBP.save(SANewPolicyAvoidanceBP.java:70)
    at com.satec.manager.SANewPolicyAvoidanceBP$$FastClassByCGLIB$$54f56c86.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.satec.manager.SANewPolicyAvoidanceBP$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$539f001e.save(<generated>)
    at com.albiran.ser.newPolicyAvoidance.NewPolicyAvoidanceServlet.handleBusinessRequest(NewPolicyAvoidanceServlet.java:64)
    at com.albiran.ser.commun.AjaxTransaction.handleBusinessRequest(AjaxTransaction.java:17)
    at com.albiran.ser.commun.AjaxTransaction$$FastClassByCGLIB$$46480d71.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.albiran.ser.commun.AjaxTransaction$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9840595b.handleBusinessRequest(<generated>)
    at com.albiran.ser.commun.AjaxServlet.executeMethod(AjaxServlet.java:208)
    at com.albiran.ser.commun.AjaxServlet.handleBusinessRequest(AjaxServlet.java:444)
    at com.albiran.ser.commun.AjaxServlet.service(AjaxServlet.java:576)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2997.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    at com.albiran.framework.license.LicenseCheckingFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckingFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at com.albiran.acces.data.acces.AlbiranSessionRequestFilter.doFilter(AlbiranSessionRequestFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.albiran.framework.license.LicenseCheckingFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckingFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:872)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Which Tomcat version are you using? JDK? Is in this test server any other application deployed? If it is, may any other existing application have another version of this jar/class loaded before?

Comment: The NoClassDefFoundError exception and it's causes are very clear but to find out the cause in your case. More information is required like environment details, when it is thrown like as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance.

Comment: The server is Jetty, and we are using JDK 1.7. And I am sorry, seems i forgot the first line of the error.  And yes its the only one running on the server.

Comment: The first line is this : 2016-08-19 15:46:35,327 ERROR (com.albiran.ser.commun.AjaxServlet:211) - Error in invocation of com.satec.manager.SANewPolicyAvoidanceBP$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$539f001e.save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand that JAXB comes with your JDK if you're using Java 6 or newer.

Normally, you would never include either JAXB API jars or JAXB implementations in your pom.xml files, because you already have access to these through the JDK. Doing so can lead to peculiar class loading problems such as those you describe.

If you ***need*** to use JAXB 2.2 then you must build and execute your code using Java 8.

Java 6 and 7 come with JAXB 2.1.

Now, the above is not true if your code is running in a full stack Java EE 6 (or newer) server such as WildFly, GlassFish, TomEE, etc.

These are spec mandated to provide a properly integrated JAXB 2.2 implementation.

In this situation you can build against JAXB 2.2 APIs. You should still exclude any implementations.

If you want to use something like Tomcat with JAXB 2.2 then you need to install the JAXB 2.2 implementation into Tomcat using it's `endorsed` directory described in the [Class Loader HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), which is built on the [Java Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/standards/). A similar solution would also be required for Jetty.